# Location result callback not calling when device is in idle mode

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am working on an app that get device location after specific time interval continuously. but the problem is `onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?)` not calling when device is in **Idle Mode**.

I have create a Foreground service for it and using `FusedLocationProviderClient` api for location.
I have also try this using `PendingIntent` instead of location callback. but got same result as `LocationCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken, when the application in idle mode starting method `onPause()`, so your location did not work. I guess you need to read about the **Activity lifecycle** and you will solve your problem.

Here the link: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle